# Containers created as global variables in C++: how the structure is managed in memory?

Tags: c++

I was wondering what happens when we create containers in c++ as global variable. My understanding is that they are created in the .data section but all the possible pointers to the elements contained in the containers and the objects they refer to, are allocated in the heap. Is that correct? Otherwise, given the fact the .data section is calculated at compile time, inserting object would create memory corruptions. Thanks!

Comment: It should go in the `.data` section if you initialize it when you define it, or in the `.bss` section if you don't initialize it. Either way, since neither of those sections is read-only, you can do stuff with them later anywhere in the program, including inserting objects (since that doesn't happen at compile-time then).

Comment: By "all the possible pointers to the elements contained in the containers and the objects they refer to, are allocated in the heap", I'm assuming you mean that the pointers will still point to memory on the heap, and the pointers themselves will not be allocated on the heap. If so, then your understanding is correct.

Comment: It depends on container. Dynamic containers (maps, sets, vector, val_array) are using heap and only small amount of data are located in place where variable is defined. Only `std::array` and `std::bitset` have everything in one place. Since C++20 `constexpr` can be used on dynamic containers and in such case heap is not in use (since such container is not mutable).

Comment: Thanks guys, much clearer